# how to escape this below sequence inorder to replace the text using sed in shell script?

Tags: shell, sed, replace

find /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/news4u -type f -exec sed -i 's/document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));/(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();/g' {} \;

This is resulting an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 93: unknown option to`s'`

I am using windows and using 'cygwin' for running shell script.

How to fix this and should single quote to be escaped since it is enclosed again in single quote?

Answer (score 0):

Escape `/` that are in the `sed` regular expressions (for example here: `google-analytics.com/ga.js`) or use other delimiters (e.g. `s^^^` instead of `s///`).

Comment: I used `find /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/news4u/apps/frontend/modules/alerts/templates -type f -exec sed -i 's/document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com\/ga.js' type='text\/javascript'%3E%3C\/script%3E"));/(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text\/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:\/\/ssl' : 'http:\/\/www') + '.google-analytics.com\/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();/g {} \;
`

Comment: I escaped `/` and it is not working. whats else to be changed ?

Comment: You must escape not only `/` but `'` also. And it would be better not to escape `/` but just use other character for delimiter of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

To escape `/` you can use another delimiter, as Igor mentioned.

Like

```
echo //// | sed 's@////@====@'
```

But there a lot of `'` that also need to be escaped.

There are at least two ways:

The first one:

```
echo "111'222\"333" | sed 's/1'\''2/___/;s/2"3/__/;'
```

The second one:

```
echo "111'222" | sed "s/1'2/___/;s/2\"3/__/;"
```

You can't just to escape `'` like `'\''`, because it absolutely doesn't matter what is between `'`. Escape character doesn't work there. So you need first to let escape character work with escaping from `'` and only then use it. Therefore we use `''\'''` construction.
However escape character works fine insede `""`, therefore you can use `"\""`.

```
find /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/news4u/apps/frontend/modules/alerts/templates \
-type f -exec sed -i "s@document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + gaJsHost + \"google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));@(function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text\/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com\/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();@g" {} \;
```

should work fine.